# Pop out window when cursor is placed on it

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

I have a table in html which displays the data from mysql db.

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Header-1</th>
       <th>Header-2</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
         <?php foreach($results as $key=>$row) { ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Data-1'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Data-2'];?></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

The number of characters in Data-1 and Data-2 are more so i want to limit to 3-4 lines maximum,but when the cursor is placed on them i want a pop out window which displays the whole data in that pop out window.How can this be done ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with CSS (or javascript) than with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make each bit of data a fixed length with the `overflow:hidden;` CSS attribute and then adapt the JSFiddle I made the other day so that when they mouse over, either the whole cell expands or a popup shows with the full data:
https://jsfiddle.net/07q6pLfj/1/

```
<div>
    <p>This is an element which does not change when you hover over it.</p>
        <div class="hover"><div class="popup">
        This is text which pops up when you hover
    </div>
        When you hover over this a popup shows.
</div>
$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".popup").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".popup").hide();
});
.popup {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
        background-color: red;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
        margin-top: 30px;
}
```